# Shrinking multiple rows to one row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to shrink multiple rows in a data frame to one row.
for example, if I have a dataframe like this,

```
  name   year  project_name month  week worklogs
  Ahkam  2019  Proj1           1      1    10
  Ahkam  2019  proj2           1      1    14
  Ahkam  2019  proj3           1      2    6
  Ahkam  2019  proj4           1      2    14
  Naser  2019  Proj1           1      1    7
  Naser  2019  proj2           1      1    8
  Naser  2019  proj3           1      2    5
  Naser  2019  proj4           1      2    3
```

and my output dataframe should be:

```
  name   year  project_name month  week worklogs
  Ahkam  2019  NaN           1      1     24
  Ahkam  2019  NaN           1      2     20
  Naser  2019  NaN           1      1     15
  Naser  2019  NaN           1      2     8
```

The project_name column may be whatever it can be. The worklogs must be added according to grouped columns(name,year,month,week)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['name', 'year', 'month', 'week'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'project_name':'first', 'worklogs':'sum'}))

print(df)
    name  year  month  week project_name  worklogs
0  Ahkam  2019      1     1        Proj1        24
1  Ahkam  2019      1     2        proj3        20
2  Naser  2019      1     1        Proj1        15
3  Naser  2019      1     2        proj3         8
```